# Microsoft Access WHERE IN Invalid Memo

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried to run the following SQL query in Microsoft Access, but received the following error: "Invalid Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery".

```
SELECT AVG(number) FROM Table 
WHERE text IN
(SELECT DISTINCT text
FROM Table
WHERE condition = FALSE);
```

Comment: What happens when you run only this part? SELECT DISTINCT text FROM Table WHERE condition = FALSE

Comment: It works and returns all the text entries that are not duplicates. Basically, I want the average of the numbers when I run SELECT DISTINCT text, number FROM Table WHERE condition = FALSE

Comment: Is this the actual code that you are using and which is generating the error? Or have you transcribed it for the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Text is memo (Long Text), you can use Distinct, and you don't have to. Thus:

```
SELECT AVG(number) 
FROM Table 
WHERE text IN
    (SELECT text
    FROM Table
    WHERE condition = FALSE);
```

But that makes little sense. You may try:

```
SELECT AVG(number) 
FROM 
    (SELECT Number
    FROM Table
    WHERE condition = FALSE
    GROUP BY Number, Left(Text, 255))
```

Comment: Thanx, the LEFT(..., <Length>) is the solution I was looking for, for retreiving a Memo in a subquery, but ofcourse you'll need to know if the <Length> is enough for what you want to retrieve. For me it did the trick with 255.